# How to check if an object exist in a GroupBox - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, object

How can I check if an object (in this case my object would be a ButtonBox) exists inside  a GroupBox but in a exact location.

Something like this :

```
If Groupbox1.NameOfButtonBox.location(40,190) exists then 
      Do my code 
end if
```

I know the syntax is completely wrong but it's just an example

Comment: *Never* test the Location property of a control.  Controls will move around when the form auto-scales on a machine with a different video DPI setting.  Why you'd want to do this is otherwise unguessable.

Comment: Well let me explain it. I have a Form with 4 buttons inside a Groupbox and each button has its own background image. What I wanted to do is check if any button exists in that exact location (each button has its own exact location) if not, a new button would be crate in that location until the Groupbox has 4 buttons ( so it would have 4 location) and then a new Groupbox would be create if the "old" one has already 4 buttons and so on. The User would provide the name for each new button.

Comment: Well, just keep track of what you did so you don't have to find it back the hard way.  When you create a button, also add it to a List(Of Button) that you store in a field of your class.  A List(Of List(Of Button)) if you want multiple group boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use this for a the button type and not a specific instance of a button, you will need to check the type of the control found.  You will also need to make sure that there is a control there.  Here is a function that will check to see if a groupbox contains a button at the given co-ordinates.

```
Private Function ButtonExists(ByVal group As GroupBox, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Boolean

    'No sense checking if there isn't a group box
    If group Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If

    'Find the control at the given point
    Dim ctrl As Control = group.GetChildAtPoint(New Point(x, y))

    'If there is a control at that point check to see if it's a button
    If ctrl IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf (ctrl) Is Button Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Briddums the code is working. 
Now I have to set the BackgroundImage for each Button dynamically.
I Have 4 Buttons and each one is named "Button1", "Button2", and so on.
So basically I have something like this : 
`For n = 1 to 4 DO 
     Button & n.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(XXXXXXX)
next`

Again I'm having problem with the Button Type because instead of having a static instance of the button, I want to have a dynamic one.

Can you Help me with this one ? 
Thanks

Comment: @EricFernandez The easiest way would be to iterate through the button controls in the groupbox.    For each ctrl as Control in Groupbox1.Controls    If Typeof(ctrl) is Button Then ctype(ctrl, Button).BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(xxx)

Answer (score 0):

Check out GetChildAtPoint:

```
Dim ctrl As Control = GroupBox1.GetChildAtPoint(New Point(147, 96))
If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
    'Do your code
End If
```

[MSDN: Control.GetChildAtPoint Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zktd23%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mike the code if working, in part...
Well the problem is that I would like to check if there is ANY ButtonBox in that location , so I wont write a specific buttonbox name in the IF statement. Something like :
<code>
Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetChildAtPoint(New Point(147, 96))
If ANYButtonBox.Equals(ctrl) Then
    'Do your code
End If
</code>

Comment: Updated the example code to more accurately reflect what you're trying to do.